# Trying to run chmod inside docker container in a single command

Tags: linux, docker, chmod

I'm trying to take the 3 commands I use below, and either make it into a single command, or put it in a script that I can call from another program.

This is what i'm currently doing:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it <my-app container id> bash
$ chmod +r /var/opt/mssql/data/myFile.bak
$ exit
```

Is there an easier way to chmod a file inside a docker container? If not, how can I put this in a single command, or a single script?

This does NOT work:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it <my-app container id> bash; chmod +r /var/opt/mssql/data/myFile.bak; exit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you have a running container, and you want to chmod a file into it. This change will likely be bound to the lifetime of the container unless that file is on a volume.

```
docker exec <my-app container id> bash -c 'chmod +r /var/opt/mssql/data/myFile.bak'
```

Execute with `sudo` if needed by your setup. Assumes `bash` is in the container's `PATH` and that the user the container is executed with has the right ownership to execute `chmod`.

You don't need `-it` because it's not an interactive session, only a single process execution inside the container.

Comment: I don't know docker, but wouldn't you be able to leave the `bash` child shell out of it completely?

Comment: Yes, binaries like `chmod` can be run directly; for running commands I prefer a more general shell-based approach so that you can literally type in what you would type in your terminal, including constructs like `&&` or `cd ...`

Comment: I was getting "Operation not permitted" with this when trying to `chown` a mounted volume. Adding `-u root` solved it.